# How do I route a port range in a linux host to a guest VM?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am trying to redirect a certain port range in a linux host to one of its guest VMs. I would like for this redirection to apply to all the host's interfaces, including localhost. I was able to do:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000:8500 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.158
```

Where 8000:8500 is the range I am interested in forwarding and 192.168.122.158 is the guest's IP. This works as long as I am trying to connect from another machine, i.e. not the VM host. But I would also like to be able to forward traffic that originates inside the VM host.

Hope that is clear, sorry if I mangled the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently performing DNAT for loopback traffic is not possible — e.g., see [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/363899/63156), or [this debian-user discussion](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2010/07/msg00703.html). Using `REDIRECT` works because traffic stays on the loopback interface, but forwarding the traffic to another machine does not work.

You could use a userspace program to forward TCP connections — e.g., xinetd with the following configuration will forward port 8000 to your VM:

```
service forward_8000
{
        type                    = UNLISTED
        port                    = 8000
        socket_type             = stream
        wait                    = no
        user                    = root
        redirect                = 192.168.122.158 8000
}
```

However, it is not possible to redirect a range of ports this way — every port needs a separate service definition.

Comment: Thank you. I found rinetd which is slightly easier to setup than xinetd for this amount of ports. I am awarding you the bounty since you provided as close to an authoritative answer as I am likely to get. take care.

Answer (score 0):

Local packets will not enter the `PREROUTING` chain. I believe you will need to use the `OUTPUT` chain in the NAT table to do that:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000:8500 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.158
```

You will possibly also need to add a rule to the filter chain that allows these outbound and their related packets:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -d 192.168.122.158 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. I get the same result, i.e., telnet localhost 8000 is unable to connect (I have something running on VM on port 8000)

Comment: You may also need to add a rule to allow the packets out. (The counterpart of your FORWARD rule.) I recommend you check your packets with tcpdump so you see what's actually happening.